# How to snap Cmder to edge on startup (Windows 7)

Tags: conemu, cmder

I managed to create a task that creates a window with 4 terminals on top of each other.

[image]

Now I want it to start snapped to the right edge, which is where I want to use it. I thought it might work like some other applications do which they remember the snap status and restore it at startup. But after some fiddling with the 'Size & Pos' couldn't make it work.

So now I'm trying to run a macro.

[image: This is from Conemu's documentation]

That can be found here http://conemu.github.io/en/KeyboardShortcuts.html

There's also this http://conemu.github.io/en/GuiMacro.html

But I can't seem to find a way to run WindowMode(7) as a macro. I tried putting it as a task parameter in various places using /GUIMACRO and -guimacro with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Just update ConEmu to latest version.

The cause of the problem is a [bug in Windows 10](http://conemu.github.io/en/MicrosoftBugs.html#SetWindowPos-10).

Initially the workaround was implemented in [170227](http://conemu.github.io/blog/2017/02/27/Build-170227.html).